# Join two lists in Rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

How to join two list together in Rego?

```
a := [1,2,3]
b := [4,5,6]
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work, not quite sure what the syntax is

```
c := a + b
```

Thank you in advance (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arrays you'd use the `array.concat` [built-in](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#arrays-2) for that purpose:

```
r := array.concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

# r == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, found the link on the website as well: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#arrays-2